# on C2D Imac, after standby/sleep the display remains dim and faded

Tags: display

on Core2Duo Imac, after standby/sleep, the display remains dim and faded.

I tried all of the suggestions I could find unsuccessfully, they mostly related to battery/power setting or modifying gnome display settings.

This was present in the V5 build and was enough of an annoyance that I discontinued using Elementary OS.  I've just tested it in the V6 release and it remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my iMac with v5.1, and also now with v6.0. However, I saw the same bright but colour faded screen with Mint upon resume. I don't know if it is a power issue because the suspend it goes into seems deeper than on the native macOS or Chromium OS which I have also tried. With the Linux versions, the sleeping mac does not respond and wake when the keyboard is pressed whereas with macOS or Chromium OS it does wake instantly. Instead, I have to press the power button once to wake it. I wonder if it is waking from a different state, and the graphics is not properly coming back.